# Why isn't export always required to export a member from a typescript namespace?

Tags: typescript

I'm confused about `export` in a typescript namespace. From my reading and testing, if a value definition is not exported from the namespace it isn't visible outside of that namespace, except I'm looking at the express package index.d.ts file and it doesn't export json, and yet this works:

```
import * as express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```

The express `index.d.ts` (edited for brevity):

```
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import serveStatic = require("serve-static");
import * as core from "express-serve-static-core";

declare function e(): core.Express;

declare namespace e {
    var json: typeof bodyParser.json;
    export function Router(options?: RouterOptions): core.Router;
}

export = e;
```

Note in the .d.ts file that `var json` is not `export var json` and yet some things are exported like `export function Router`.

Why does accessing `express.json` work, and since it does, why does the `function Router` need to be exported?